# Extrating the digits before the decimal point with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am using Powershell and need to extract the digits before the decimal point so that I can evaluate the number extracted

So with  `$Interest_Rate = 15.5`

I have tried the following code .. but they do not work:

```
$Interest_RatePart1 = "{0:N0}" -f $Interest_Rate
```

It rounds the value to 16

```
$Interest_RatePart1 = ($Interest_Rate -split '.')[0].trim()
```

It returns a blank.
I just want to return 15

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Formatting the number will cause rounding away from zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35808409/why-do-the-numeric-format-strings-in-c-sharp-round-the-number-when-not-using-dec)

Use [`Math.Truncate()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d101hyf(v=vs.110).aspx) - which always rounds *towards zero* - instead:

```
$Interest_RatePart1 = [Math]::Truncate($Interest_Rate)
```

---

FWIW, the reason your last attempt returns nothing, is because `-split` defaults to regular expressions, and `.` means *any character* in regex.

Either escape the `.` with `\`:

```
$Interest_RatePart1 = ($Interest_Rate -split '\.')[0].Trim()
```

or specify that it shouldn't use regex:

```
$Interest_RatePart1 = ($Interest_Rate -split '.', 2, 'SimpleMatch')[0].Trim()
```

or use the `String.Split()` method instead:

```
$Interest_RatePart1 = "$Interest_Rate".Split('.')[0].Trim()
```

Answer (score 2):

Mathias' `[Math]::Truncate` is correct - some other options for you though, pay attention to `Floor` as it is [Slightly Different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14/difference-between-math-floor-and-math-truncate) to `Truncate` when working with negative numbers.

- Cast to int (can round up)

  ```
  [int]$Interest_Rate
  ```
- Use `[Math]::Floor` (will always round down, similar to truncate for non-negative numbers)

  ```
  [Math]::Floor($Interest_Rate)
  ```
- Use `[Math]::Round` with `0` decimal places. (can round up)

  ```
  [Math]::Round($Interest_Rate, 0)
  ```

Comment: `Math.Truncate()` _always_ rounds toward zero (basically truncating the _absolute value_ of the input argument), it's similar to your last example rather than `Math.Floor()`

Comment: Truncate: `[math]::Truncate(1.5) == 1`, `[math]::Truncate(2.5) == 2`, `[math]::Truncate(-1.5) == -1`, `[math]::Truncate(-2.5) == -2`

Comment: Floor: `[math]::Floor(1.5) == 1`, `[math]::Floor(2.5) == 2`, `[math]::Floor(-1.5) == -2`, `[math]::Floor(-2.5) == -3`

Comment: Round: `[math]::Round(1.5, 0) == 2`,`[math]::Round(2.5, 0) == 2`, `[math]::Round(-1.5, 0) == -2`, `[math]::Round(-2.5, 0) == -2`

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers nice. You could also implement `Truncate()` using `Floor()` and `Abs()`: `$v = 1.5; [Math]::Floor([Math]::Abs($v)) * (1,-1)[$v -lt 0]`